# Convert python dictionary lists to a tree format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Our crawling team has captured industry information on shopping sites such as.

```
industry_list = [
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "shirt"
  },
  {
     "name": "Clothing"
  },
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "jeans"
  },
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "Dress"
  },
  {
     "name": "Digital Products"
  },
  {
    "parent_ind" : "Digital Products",
     "name": "computer parts"
  },
  {
    "parent_ind" : "computer parts",
     "name": "Hard Disk"
  },
]
```

For ease of access, we would like to be able to convert this to a tree format, for example:

```
{
  "Digital Products": {
    "computer parts": {
        "Hard Disk" : {}
     }
  },
  "Clothing" : {
     "shirt": {},
    "jeans": {},
    "Dress": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I know it's probably going to be recursive? I just can't figure out how to write it yet......

Comment: @Robert isn't wrong. Though, this is kind of a fun problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in O(n) time by initializing a links dictionary with all names plus a None entry for the root.  Then add each child to its parent's sub-dictionary (no recursion needed). The root of the links dictionary will point to the final tree:

```
links = { d["name"]:{} for d in industry_list }
tree  = links[None] = dict()
for d in industry_list:
    name,parent = d["name"],d.get("parent_ind",None)
    links[parent].update({name:links[name]})
```

output:

```
print(tree)

{ 'Clothing':
   { 'shirt': {}, 'jeans': {}, 'Dress': {} },
  'Digital Products':
   { 'computer parts':
     {'Hard Disk': {}}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
result = {}
for i in industry_list: 
    if i.get('parent_ind'): 
        parent = i.get('parent_ind') 
        if parent not in result: 
            result[parent] = {} 
        del i['parent_ind'] 
        for key, val in result.items(): 
            if parent in val: 
                result[key][parent][i['name']] = {} 
            else: 
                result[parent][i['name']] = {} 
        key_as_val =  any(parent in d.keys() for d in result.values()) 
        if key_as_val is True: 
            del result[parent]
```

`result`:

```
{
    'Clothing': {
        'shirt': {},
        'jeans': {},
        'Dress': {}
    }, 
    'Digital Products': {
        'computer parts': {
            'Hard Disk': {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work I believe... Obviously you'll need to modify it to suit your needs. Right now, you can use this script to print out the accessTree you're after. You'll want to adopt the internal logic and have a python script that dynamically reads your industry lists.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

industry_list = [
    {
        "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
        "name" : "shirt"
    },
    {
        "name": "Clothing"
    },
    {
        "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
        "name" : "jeans"
    },
    {
        "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
        "name" : "Dress"
    },
    {
        "name": "Digital Products"
    },
    {
        "parent_ind" : "Digital Products",
        "name": "computer parts"
    },
    {
        "parent_ind" : "computer parts",
        "name": "Hard Disk"
    }
]

# Initialize an access tree object
accessTree = {}

# Recursive object search function
def _findItem(obj, key):
    if key in obj: return obj[key]
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            item = _findItem(v, key)
            if item is not None:
                return obj[k][key]

# For each item in the industry list
for listItem in industry_list:
    # Recursively check if there is a parent industry
    if "parent_ind" in listItem.keys():
        parentInd = listItem["parent_ind"]
        itemName = listItem["name"]

        parentObject = _findItem(accessTree, parentInd)

        # If so, add it to the object
        if parentObject is not None:
            parentObject[itemName] = {}

        # Otherwise, add it
        elif parentObject is None:
            accessTree[parentInd] = {}
            accessTree[parentInd][itemName]= {}

print("Final Access Tree as follows: \n")

pp.pprint(accessTree)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
industry_list = [
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "shirt"
  },
  {
     "name": "Clothing"
  },
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "jeans"
  },
  {
     "parent_ind" : "Clothing",
     "name" : "Dress"
  },
  {
     "name": "Digital Products"
  },
  {
    "parent_ind" : "Digital Products",
     "name": "computer parts"
  },
  {
    "parent_ind" : "computer parts",
     "name": "Hard Disk"
  },
]

new_industry_list = {}
where_map = {}

while industry_list:
    for i, d in enumerate(industry_list):
        if 'parent_ind' not in d: # no parent
            the_dict = {}
            new_industry_list[d['name']] =  the_dict
            where_map[d['name']] = the_dict
            del industry_list[i]
            break
        if d['parent_ind'] in where_map: # its parent is in the new dictionary and this is where
            the_dict = {}
            where_map[d['parent_ind']][d['name']] = the_dict
            where_map[d['name']] = the_dict
            del industry_list[i]
            break

print(new_industry_list)
```

Prints:

```
{'Clothing': {'shirt': {}, 'jeans': {}, 'Dress': {}}, 'Digital Products': {'computer parts': {'Hard Disk': {}}}}
```